# Is there a way to fix vim not-noticing python if statements that have comments?

Tags: python, vim

Consider the following block of code-

```
if (1==1):#Go forever
    print "Wooo."
```

Vim doesn't see the :, due to the comment, so it insists that the print should be at the same indent level as the "if"

using http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=974

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: I have had this same issue as long as I can remember.  My solution... I don't put comments on the line like that.

Comment: just to clarify: you use a script from 2005 which claims to get the indention closer to what PEP wants because you are unhappy with the way a vanilla vim indents python code (which indents your provided sample just right, btw)?

Comment: To be fair, the indent/python.vim file in Vim 7.2 is from 2006 according to its header. It isn't that much newer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find this in the .vim file:

```
" If the previous line ended with a colon, indent relative to
" statement start.
if pline =~ ':\s*$'
```

change it to...

```
" If the previous line ended with a colon, indent relative to
" statement start.
if pline =~ ':\s*\(#.*\)\?$'
```

That will make it also match lines that end with a colon followed by a comment.

Comment: Vim needs a few more backslashes: `if pline =~ ':\s*\%(#.*\\)\?$'`